# How can I get rid of an Unstable Node quickly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

So I'm an admin of a minecraft server, and I've discovered that the wisps near my server's spawn arn't just the result of a spawner, there is actually a very large (over 500 vis) unstable node about 100 meters from the spawn area generating them. This is causing all kinds of issues as I have people joining the server and getting practically insta-gibbed by a swarm of wisps. How can I get rid of the node quickly?

(I'm using Thaumcraft 3)

Comment: What thaumcraft version are we talking about? 3 or 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make note of the node's position in the world.

Using this: http://dinnerbone.com/minecraft/tools/coordinates/

Find the chunk and region file that the node is in, and take note of them.

Then:

1. Stop the server ( maintenance weekend! )
2. MAKE A BACKUP OF THE WORLD!!!! (just in case, Murphy is watching)
3. Using NBTExplorer, or a similar program, open the region file who's name you took down earlier (it will be in SERVERFOLDER/WORLDFOLDER/region/)
4. Locate the chunk in the file that your node is in, I find it helpful to put something obvious there so I can find it later, like a named mob, whose name I can search for to find the chunk.
5. Look in the TCNODES section of the chunk, here is where thaumcraft stores it's nodes.
6. you can just delete the node in it's entirety, or you can set it's type to 1 (pure node) and delete all entries under Flux.

That's all there is to it.

You can now go on a whisp-killing-spree!!!

Answer (score 1):

theres no "easy" way to get rid of a node. you can purify the node with bees (although the bee-breeding line is a pain in itself) or grow few silverwood trees nearby, as they purify the area at a slow rate.

You can also try moving the node, (top tier research item, cant remember its name), but that also uses a lot of vis and generates a mess in itself.

If you own the server you could try regenerating aura nodes if that corrupt node was created by something else.

Comment: please explain how I can purify the node with bees. I own the server, and am willing to cheat in whatever I need to in order to fix this issue, as it's ruining the experience for my new players.

Comment: a pure bee (or group of them depending on how bad the node is) will eat the flux and poop it out as shards to use in other things. Which will clean up the area rather quickly. http://ftbwiki.org/Pure_Bee You could also try using a Node bee to slowly move the unstable node away

Comment: If I'm reading this correclty this would require me to keep the bee's there, it doesn't fix the problem, it merely suspends it.

Answer (score -2):

turn nodes off in the config files. restart the map. quit. then turn the nodes back on. will replace all nodes throughout the game. worked for me